Laravel - batchable jobs with negative value
In my jobs_batch table, some batch jobs have the "pending_jobs" field at -1 instead of 0 after all jobs have been dispatch. When the field is negative I noticed that it is duplicating the same job
public function __construct(protected array $jobs)
{
}

public function dispatchBus()
{
$batch = Bus::batch($this->jobs)->finally(function (Batch $batch) {
            $invoice = new InvoiceService($batch->id);
            $invoice->send(); //send laravel notification
        })
        ->allowFailures()
        ->onQueue('invoice')
        ->dispatch();

return $batch;
}
  

my individual job from the array of jobs that is sent to the batch
class InvoiceJob implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Batchable, Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(protected Plan $plan, protected companyModel $company, protected bool $sandbox = false)
    {
    }
    
    public $uniqueFor = 3600;
    public $tries = 3;


    public function uniqueId(): string
    {
        return $this->plan->id;
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        if ($this->batch()->cancelled()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            $invoiceService = new InvoiceService($this->company, sandbox: $this->sandbox, batch_id: $this->batch()->id);
            $invoice = $invoiceService->apiExec($this->plan);

            if ($this->plan->client->type === 'pj') {
                $invoiceService->sendEmail($invoice);
            }
        } catch (Throwable $exception) {
            Batch::addLog($this->batch()->id, "Fail: {$this->plan->client->code} - {$this->plan->client->name}
            Erro: {$exception->getMessage()}");
            $this->fail();
        }
    }
}

What causes this to have this batch behavior with a negative value?
